# Change output folder of the .dll for the generated solution of CANoe

Tags: c#, .net, capl, canoe

I want to change the output folder for the .dll file of the solution generated by CANoe (.net Test Node).
I changed the output folder in Visual Studio, but now I can't build it from CANoe, because CANoe doesn't see the new location of the output file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. CANoe does not have this option.
Change the output forder from VS and from CANoe change the .cs file to the new .dll